# ArrayList of Arraylist elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Integer(la) and an Arraylist of Arraylist of Integer(L)
I need to take numbers from a matrix in la and then add in L.
If I remove all elements from la, L is [[],[],[]]

L must be [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int [][]A = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    ArrayList<Integer> la = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> L = new ArrayList< ArrayList<Integer>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            la.add(A[i][j]);
        }
        L.add(la);
        la.clear();
    }

    System.out.println(L);    
}
```

Comment: What do you think `la.clear();` does?

Comment: It's better to use `List<List<Integer>> L = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`

Comment: Can you tell us what do you expect from 
    la.clear()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing `la` and clearing it. Since this reference is shared because of its scope, you are going to end up with an `ArrayList` (`L`) of empty `ArrayLists`. You need to declare it in your inner loop.

```
 int [][]A = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

 ArrayList< ArrayList<Integer> > L = new ArrayList< ArrayList<Integer> >();
 for(int i=0; i<3; i++ )
 {
      ArrayList< Integer > la = new ArrayList< Integer >(); 
      for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
      {
          la.add(A[i][j]);
      }
      L.add(la);
  }
```

Note: I haven't tested that, but it should get you closer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand you fully, but I think you need to copy an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList a;
ArrayList b = new ArrayList(a);
```

That way you won't be referencing the same ArrayLists in multiple places.